# ASP/SQL: Group Data into colums

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a view where I group customer and company from different months, so that I only have one customer/company in overall.

What I want to do is to get all the customer (grouped) and the column `Money` from all the months into a new table where the Months(Money) are columns. How can I do this in SQL? So that maybe customer xy has money 1 in January but it's possible to get NULL in February and so on....

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it it's a simple join, like this:

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (ID int, Name varchar(100))
DECLARE @January TABLE (CustomerId int, Money decimal)
DECLARE @February TABLE (CustomerId int, Money decimal)
DECLARE @March TABLE (CustomerId int, Money decimal)

INSERT INTO @Customer (id, name) VALUES (1, 'C1')
INSERT INTO @Customer (id, name) VALUES (2, 'C2')
INSERT INTO @Customer (id, name) VALUES (3, 'C3')

INSERT INTO @January (CustomerId, Money) VALUES (1, 500)
INSERT INTO @January (CustomerId, Money) VALUES (2, 300)

INSERT INTO @February (CustomerId, Money) VALUES (2, 100)
INSERT INTO @February (CustomerId, Money) VALUES (3, 200)

INSERT INTO @march (CustomerId, Money) VALUES (1, 700)
INSERT INTO @march (CustomerId, Money) VALUES (2, 600)

SELECT DISTINCT c.*, j.Money as Money_January, f.Money as Money_February, m.Money as Money_March 
FROM @Customer c
LEFT JOIN @January j ON c.Id = j.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN @February f ON c.Id = f.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN @March m ON c.Id = m.CustomerId
```

Comment: Works with the example but unfortunately takes minutes to execute when data is about 100000 rows and more....

Comment: Add indexes on CustomerId for Months tables. I assume Id is primary key in Customer table.

Comment: Unfortunately not, its like Customer 1,2,2,4 and Cusomter_id 1,2,2,4. So you can have Customer and Cusotmer_id multiple times in the months tables. But its ok to group and then it would be a perfect identitier. Maybe a good way to do it is to create view with just cumstomer,customer,money and group them too and then join on customer table? I already create the custoemr group with an identifier on customer id and then join the monthly tables but it also takes several minutes...